# How to integrate $\int \ln(\ln(x))dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate

$$\int \ln(\ln(x))dx?$$

I am trying this question by substituting $\ln(x)=u$. Therefore $\frac{1}{x}dx=du$. Therefore $dx=e^{u}du$. So, the integral will become

$$\int (\ln(u))e^{u}du.$$

Now I am thinking of applying Integration by Parts. So, here according to the rule of ILATE, $u=(\ln(u))$ and $v=e^{u}$. Let $I=(\ln(u))e^{u}$. Now after applying IBP we will get

$$I= (\ln(u))e^{u}-\int \frac{e^{u}}{u}du.$$

[Because $\int e^{u}du=e^{u}$]. But after this step, I can't proceed further. Please help me out. Because, I am facing problem in integrating $$\int \frac{e^{u}}{u}du.$$

Comment: Use IBP with $x$ as first function and $ln(ln(x))$ as second function and see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)

Comment: Please show me the full solution.

Comment: See : https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-take-the-integral-of-ln-ln-x. Besides, what is the "rule of ILATE" ? Never heard of it...

Comment: @JeanMarie I think it's basically a fancy name for integration by parts, see [this](https://youtu.be/z33rYYUM4d8?si=TX97yOY4spTtJyGp)

Comment: @Sine of the Time Thanks. In fact, the right term looks to be LIATE (that I didn't know more that ILATE !)

Comment: I'm gonna play devil's advocate and and say I wouldn't call the ILATE thing a rule, despite what many sources claim it as. It's more of a tool to help beginners choose which part to differentiate and which part to integrate. But it's not officially recognized as a formal statement in mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int \ln(\ln x)dx = \int (\ln(\ln x) + \frac{1}{\ln x} - \frac{1}{\ln x})dx$$

$$= \int d(x\cdot\ln(\ln x)) - \int \frac{1}{\ln x}dx$$

$$ = x\cdot\ln(\ln x) + c - \int \frac{1}{\ln x}dx$$

The right hand side integral is also known as "logarithmic integral" and is denoted by $\operatorname{li}(x)$. Thus:

$$\int \ln(\ln x)dx = x\cdot\ln x(\ln x) - \operatorname{li}(x) +c$$

Edit: About the question owner's result $e^u.\ln u - \int \frac{e^u}{u}du$ is same result with I found. Just reverse the substitutions $u = \ln x$ :

$$e^{\ln x} . \ln(\ln x) - \int \frac{e^{\ln x}}{\ln x} \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$x. \ln(\ln x) - \int \frac{1}{\ln x} dx$$
$$x. \ln(\ln x) - \operatorname{li}(x)$$

I would like to say that the integral $\int \frac{e^u}{u}du$ is also known as "exponential integral".

Both exponential and logarithmic integrals can't be represented with standart mathematical functions. Actually you found the correct result.

Comment: But for $\operatorname{li}$ you need `\operatorname{li}`

Comment: @GEdgar how do you write in code like that?

Comment: What is $li(x)$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh To get `\operatornams{li}`, surroud by single backquotes ` and `  .  Generally, `\operatorname{}` has proper spacing for a multi-letter operator name, whereas `\text{}` may not.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is the "logarithmic integral" defined by $\operatorname{li}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\ln t}$.